# Matplotlib: How to give color to scatterplot circles based on column values

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have data comprising of 3 columns:

```
zone | pop1 | pop2
----   ----   ----
3      4500   3800
2      2800   3100
1      1350   1600
2      2100   1900
3      3450   3600
```

I would like to draw a scatter plot of `pop1` and `pop2`, with the circles having colors based on the value of `zone`.

I have the following code so far:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
plt.scatter(df['pop1'],df['pop2'], s = 1)
```

How can I give different colors, let's say red, green and blue, corresponding to zone values 1, 2 and 3 respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using an additional library, you can also go for something like:

```
colors = {1:'red', 2:'green', 3:'blue'}

for i in range(len(df)):
    plt.scatter(df['pop1'].iloc[i], df['pop2'].iloc[i],
                c=colors[df['zone'].iloc[i]])
```

EDIT: You dont need to use a loop, you can use something like this:

```
colors = {1:'red', 2:'green', 3:'blue'}

plt.scatter(df['pop1'], df['pop2'], 
            c=[colors[i] for i in df['zone']])
```

Which gives the output:

[image]

This requires you to make a dictionary of colors for the values in `zones` though. Also you will spend some extra time making the list comprehension.

Comment: For large datasets, this approach would be taking a lot of time.

Comment: You are correct. I have update the answer to avoid the the loop. There is still a list comprehension that needs to be done, but I expect that to be much faster than repeated calls to `plt.scatter`

Comment: Yes, much faster now. I have selected it as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use seaborn package, which use matplotlib wrapper. It has varieties of features with beautiful plots. Here is simple example to your question.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[4500,2800,1350,2100,3450],
             'col2':[3800,3100 ,1650,1900,3600],
             'col3':[3,2,1,2,3]})

sns.lmplot(data=data, x='col1', y='col2', hue='col3', 
                   fit_reg=False, legend=True)
#fit_reg is use to fit a line for regression, we need only dots.
```

[image]

Comment: Can you control the colors here? Maybe its not important for the OP, but the colors corresponding to a particular value are specified in the question.